# How to transform XML to HTML using XSLT in ANDROID?

Tags: java, android, xml, transform, xslt

I am working on a android(2.2) project which needs xsl transformation. The below code works perfectly in a regular non-android java project

```
public static String transform() throws TransformerException {
    Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new File("samplexml.xml"));
    Source xslInput = new StreamSource(new File("samplexslt.xslt"));

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslInput); 

    OutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Result result = new StreamResult(baos);
    transformer.transform(xmlInput, result);
    return baos.toString();
}
```

I need similar functionality on android. For this I created 2 files under resources/raw:

1. samplexml.xml
2. samplexslt.xslt

(contents of these files come from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex1).

I tried the below code & it does not work (note the StreamSource constructor arg):

```
public static String transform() throws TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.samplexml));
    Source xslInput = new StreamSource(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.samplexslt));

    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslInput);//NullPointerException here
    OutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Result result = new StreamResult(baos);
    transformer.transform(xmlInput, result);
}
```

I saw the spec & believe I need to set a systemId. But I couldn't get the above code to work.

So, in an android project, how to handle xslt transformations? Please provide your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

As we know that `we Cannot use`***`this`***`in a static context` and you are doing this in your static method `transform()`. You can do it like this_

```
public class YourLoadXSLClass extends Activity {
static Resources res;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    res = getResources();

    String strHTML = transform();
    // Other code.....

}

/*
 * Your method that Transform CSLT.
 */
public static String transform() throws TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    // Now your raw files are accessible here.
    Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(
            LoadXSLTinWebview.res.openRawResource(R.raw.samplexml));
    Source xslInput = new StreamSource(
            LoadXSLTinWebview.res.openRawResource(R.raw.samplexslt));

    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslInput);

    OutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Result result = new StreamResult(baos);
    transformer.transform(xmlInput, result);
    return baos.toString();
 }

}
```

> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318998/how-to-transform-xml-with-xslt-and-display-it-in-android-webview/19402040#19402040) is the complete class code that do the needful. I hope this will help you & all!

Comment: Thank you for saving my day ;) I used Strings for the transformer(from another example) which game me errors (no version), but with this answer (including Source) I got the transformationfactory working without any problems!

Answer (score 0):

I've never done anything with XSLT but, looking at your code, logically there are only two things that could cause an NPE on that line. The first would be that `factory` might be `null` but that doesn't make sense.

That leaves `xslInput` as being the culprit which suggests  `openRawResource(R.raw.samplexslt)` is failing to return a valid `InputStream` for the `StreamSource` constructor to use. Try putting a log statement in such as...

```
if (xslInput != null {
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslInput);
    ...
}
else
    Log.d("SomeTAG", "xslInput is null!!!");
```

If it turns out that `xslInput` is actually `null` then it suggests `openRawResource(...)` can't find/process the .xslt file properly. In that case I'd suggest using `AssetManager`to open the .xslt file by name...

```
AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
Source xslInput = new StreamSource(am.open("samplexslt.xslt"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, the "transformer" is coming back as null. Sorry for not being clear on that. Now, I tried the AssetManager approach you suggested, but still get NPE.

Comment: OK, that's strange. At the moment I can't think of any reason why that might happen.