# How to transform xml with xslt and display it in Android webview

Tags: xml, xslt, webview, transform

I am trying to display the xml data, which was transformed by xsl file, onto the webview in an Android application.  However, the data is not displayed as expected.

```
XML file used (cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml)  -- Sample xml data
--------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>


XSL file used (cdcatalog.xsl)  -- Sample xsl file
-----------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Would some body help me with a sample code to load this data into webview of Android app?

Comment: You probably need to be more specific about what the expected output is.

Comment: I can't upload the screen shot of the output...however, the expected is to display a table with two columns and two rows of data from the xml.

Answer (score 11):

Its quite tricky, i try to make it easy to understand. Just follow below steps_

1. Build your XSLT file under res/raw,
2. either parse your XML or be ready with your XML(in res/raw)
3. Finally, consume these to display in Android Webview

your `cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml` & `cdcatalog.xsl` must be there in ***`res/raw`***. I have build *LoadXSLTinWebview* that servers your need_

```
public class LoadXSLTinWebview extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);

    //Reading XSLT
    String strXSLT = GetStyleSheet(R.raw.cdcatalog);
    //Reading XML
    String strXML = GetStyleSheet(R.raw.cdcatalog_with_xsl);
    /*
     * Loading XSLT...
     */
      //Transform ...
      String html=StaticTransform(strXSLT, strXML);
      //Loading the above transformed CSLT in to Webview...
      webview.loadData(html,"text/html",null);

}

/*
 * Transform XSLT to HTML string
 */
public static String StaticTransform(String strXsl, String strXml) {
    String html = "";

    try {

        InputStream ds = null;
        ds = new ByteArrayInputStream(strXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(ds);

        InputStream xs = new ByteArrayInputStream(strXsl.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xs);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Result result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
        transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);

        html = writer.toString();

        ds.close();
        xs.close();

        xmlSource = null;
        xsltSource = null;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return html;
}

/*
 * Read file from res/raw...
 */
private String GetStyleSheet(int fileId) {
    String strXsl = null;

        InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(fileId);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int size = 0;
        // Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while ((size = raw.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
            raw.close();

            strXsl = outputStream.toString();

            Log.v("Log", "xsl ==> " + strXsl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return strXsl;

}

}
```

***`OutPut:`***

[image: output]

I hope this will help all!

Comment: Yes this helps me a lot. Thanks for posting this which saves my time.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Only noticed that you change XML and XSL in the onCreate. You should change this, first time I tried this code it wasn't working. Its only a change of 2 string names ;)