# Compiling schema to XSLT in Android

Tags: android, xml, xslt, schematron

My goal is to validate some XML document against Schematron file in Android.
At the moment I am trying to use this [library](http://www.probatron.org/probatron4j.html) for Java.
So far, it doesn't seem to be working at all, I simply get empty array as the result of transform. This is piece of code from the library method I adjusted a bit.

```
Source xsltSource = (Source) jur.resolve( "iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl", null );
Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(this.schemaAsStream);
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
transformer.transform(xsltSource,  new StreamResult( baos ));
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get Transformer working for Android?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations (XSLT)` APIs can be used for many purposes. For example, with a sufficiently intelligent stylesheet, you could generate PDF or PostScript output from the XML data. But generally, XSLT is used to generate formatted `HTML` output (that we can consume in our `Android Webview`), or to create an alternative XML representation of the data.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318998/how-to-transform-xml-with-xslt-and-display-it-in-android-webview/19402040#19402040) will help you.